# Wordpress redirects to IP instead of domain

Tags: domains, amazon-ec2, wordpress

Following [this blog post](http://iampuneet.com/wordpress-amazon-ec2/) I set up Wordpress on an EC2 instance. I've pointed A records to my Amazon EC Elastic IP Address.

After propagation, when I open my website with the domain name, it works. But when I click on other page, it just redirects me to my IP address instead.

Comment: How is your web site and web server set up? We're missing too many details to be able to answer this. What operating system, what web server, what kind of website are you running? How is it configured?

Comment: I've set-up website on "console.aws.amazon.com" and got elastic IP after setting, my domain answersmine.com set "A" name records. After propogate, home page open corectly but not others associate page

Comment: We already know that. What web server do you run and how did you configure your home page? For example, do you use Apache and virtual hosts?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm new and did myself. that's why not ask with incomplete question. I've set-up as per one tutorials "http://iampuneet.com/wordpress-amazon-ec2/" and add "A record" into my DNS. Really I need help.

Answer (score 3):

This could be caused by the settings you are using in WordPress.

When you first install WordPress it remembers the host name you used to run the installer, and uses that.

Log in to your WordPress admin panel, go to Settings > General in the menu.

Check that the fields for both 'WordPress Address (URL)' and 'Site Address (URL)' have the correct site address that you want to use.

Comment: Its work now. Thanks...
One more problem here. permalink structure is not working, is any command/or plugin from that I can fix permalink problem.

Comment: That problem is a little more difficult to figure out without more information. What I would do is deactivate any plugins you have and try it again. if the permalinks work that way you can enable the plugins one-by-one until you find the one that's causing the problem. If I was able to help you solve your original problem you can mark my answer as the 'accepted answer' by clicking the check mark beside it.